# Why are galactic nuclei yellow?

Tags: star, galaxy, redshift, supermassive-black-hole

So we've seen millions of galaxies, and all of them have a bright, yellow nucleus. What is the cause of the yellowness? Is it because of aging stars, redshift from the SMBH, or something else?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It's an observational fact that many disk galaxies have a color gradient with redder (or as you say 'yellow') stars in the central regions and bluer stars in the disk.
There are two things that can cause this central redness.

- Age, older stars being redder than younger stars
- Metallicity, with red stars being more metal rich than blue stars

Whether it's age or metallicity or both causing these gradients is topic of current research. It's a popular [theory](https://iopscience.iop.org/article/10.1088/2041-8205/764/1/L1/pdf) that galaxies grow inside-out, which causes a red center.